# Javascript Variables initialization types

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know the difference between these three types of variable initialization.

1)- The first type is using the "this" keyword.

```
var x=function (data1,data2){
this.data1=data1;
this.data2=data2;
}
```

2)- Second is using the "var" keyword...from what i know the var keyword makes the scope of a variable local which means that var can only be accessible when we are inside the function.

```
var x=function (data1,data2){
var data1=data1;
var data2=data2;
}
```

3)- Third type is without using any keyword..from what i know is that we don't specify the var keyword with a variable then it becomes global for the complete application. So you can access it any where you want...but in this case i think this would throw an error...because how would javascript know if data1 is a variable or a parameter (the passed on argument) ?

```
var x=function (data1,data2){
data1=data1;
data2=data2;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Steve. I just gave you what I know off the top of my head. There are more details than can be useful in a Stackoverflow post, but I think I pointed you in the right direction. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

**1)** `this.foo = bar`

The first kind you mention makes your variables properties of a (constructor) function. In JavaScript, functions are objects. Thus, using `this` makes a variable a property of an object (your constructor function, in this case).

**2)** `var x = 7`

Let me start off saying that anytime you do not use `var` in front of a variable (save for the `this` stuff above), that variable will become a member of the global context object (`window`, for most user-agents).

Thought leaders in JavaScript and programming see global variables as a sin, or *code smell*. Avoid global variables as much as possible.

The issue with the first method (`this`) is that prior to ECMAScript 5, there was no good way to enforce privacy on object properties (as you might find in the classical C++ based languages like Java, PHP, etc). ECMAScript 5 and above allow you to assign `attributes` to properties for things like writability, enumerability, etc...

However, as it pertains to `var`, well, `var` always makes its variables private to the function object. You cannot access a var variable from external, client code like this

```
dog.age = 5 //Trying to assign the number five to a var variable.
```

You can make a function that has access (known as an accessor), though. In effect, when you see `var`, think private to this object's scope. That's the gist of it. *Closure* (from enclosure) is an important subject in JavaScript. When you get into using `var`, inevitably you start to learn about closure.

**3)** No key word.

Finally, using naked variables attaches all of them to the global object (`window`, for most user-agents). This tends to lead to confusion and debugging issues. You may inadvertently stage a collision or conflict where a value is being changed across many instances of your constructor function. It's just not the way to go.

In summary, a fantastic book on the subject of JavaScript variables is [The Principles of Object Oriented JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593275404). Mr. Zakas explains things much better than Crockford and Flannagan. I highly recommend it. Know your goal. Know your problem. Avoid global variables. Learn about JavaScript's object mode and scope. I recommend [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805527) when it comes to learning about scope and context in JavaScript.

Comment: Note: JavaScript may have a flexible and logical object model, but it does not mean I have to like it!